# how to get text from a clipboard in javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, clipboard

how can I get a text saved in the clipboard to a string using javascript? (or if it is to an image an image object) if it requires any  permission just state which one (i use it in a chrome extension, so what should I add to the manifest in the `permissions`  arrays?)

(don't worry, I know it sounds suspicious.  I don't use the data in any form of abusive way, but for a clipboard chrome extension.)

Comment: Have a look at [`Clipboard.readText`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

You can use the [`ClipBoard API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

Per an example on MDN:

```
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
  clipText => document.querySelector(".editor").innerText += clipText);
```

Keep in mind that this is **Asynchronous** so you'll need to have your functions based on that Promise.

---

### Aside:

Currently the ClipBoard API is not compatible with `Internet Explorer`, and other than  `FireFox` with feature flags set, reading is the only thing allowed. This may change in the future, but just be aware that you can't expect to alter the ClipBoard through the API.

For fallback purposes you would have to use `document.execCommand` and most likely as follows:

```js
let el = document.querySelector.bind(document);

let btn = el("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let i = el("input");

//empty input
  i.value = "";
//focus input
  i.focus();

//paste into input
  document.execCommand("paste");
  
//do something with pasted string
  console.log(i.textContent);
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<input class="hidden">
<small>Note: This should only work in IE.</small>
<button>Get String</button>
```

Comment: This should only work in IE? but i build an extension to chrome?